# How to handle extraction of double type numbers from a complex input (string)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, input

Good day to you all,

I am kinda new to C programming and I've stumbled upon a problem that am trying to address properlly for a few days now but still with no satisfying results.

I am trying to extract some `double` values from a user given input in this form `{[ 5.1 ; 4 ], [15.3 ; -3.2] }`. I tried many approaches, the best one so far is that I read user input as a string using `fgets()`, loop through with `for` and if `isdigit()` sees a digit I store it in another string, then I check if there is a dot right after the digit, if there is then I put it to the string right behind the digit and so on and so forth.

The real problem is when I want to output the resultant string and convert it to my desired `double` with `strtod()` it works only if the user inputs some digits first, but if the input looks something like `{ [ 2.5 ; 1 ] }` the code just don't care and does nothing. Any help or insights would be much appreciated, maybe I am taking a wrong approach? Thank you.

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 256

int main() {

char t1[STR_LEN], digits[STR_LEN], *dpt, per[2] = ".";
int i, digit, period;
double x;

fgets(t1, STR_LEN, stdin);

for (i = 0; i < strlen(t1); i++) {
    digit = isdigit(t1[i]);
    period = (t1[i + 1] == '.') ? 1 : 0;
    if (digit) {
        digits[i] = t1[i];
    }
    if (period == 1) {
        strcpy(digits, digits);
        strcat(digits, per);
    }
}
x = strtod(digits, &dpt);
int testOutput = strlen(digits);
printf("%s %d %lf", digits, testOutput, x);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(t1); i++) {`  the function `strlen()` returns a `size_t`  which is an unsigned long.  The variable `i` is an `int`, which is signed. It would be better, in this case, if the variable `i` were declared as `size_t i;`  as comparing signed and unsigned variables is 'iffy'

Comment: regarding: `int testOutput = strlen(digits);`  This is assigning an `unsigned long` value to an `int`.  This will work in most instances, but not always, (depends on the actual values used).  Suggest: `size_t testOutput = strlen(digits);` and then modifying the call to `printf()` to use a format string of: `"%s %lu %lf" (or similar)

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:   1) consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) separate code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.

Comment: `strcpy(digits, digits);` is, at best, a no-op. But, `strcpy` isn't [necessarily] designed to have the same or overlapping arguments, so it could do damage. I _think_ you don't need/want it

Comment: suggest using the function: `strtod()`.   then just index through the read in line, and each time the function indicates success (!=0) then index forward using the second parameter to the function.  I.E. don't bother to mess with the individual digits at all

Comment: Do you know about `scanf`/`sscanf`?

Comment: the posted code will (at best) only display the final number and not the others..   BTW: why call `strtol()`  just treat all the numbers as doubles

Comment: You can use `strtok_r` to tokenize a string. For example, first tokenize by `;`, then by space and you got 2 strings of numbers to pass to `strtod`.

Comment: @emi Your solution with the tokenizing is also very effective, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a *separate* index variable (different from `i`) when indexing into `digits`. This is because if your input is (e.g. `; 37.5`) `i` will be misaligned on `digits`

Also, when you copy over a digit into `digits`, you have to add an EOS terminator to keep the string whole [so that the `strcat` would not run off the end of the `digits` string].

You don't want to use `t1[i + 1]` in the loop. It could go beyond the end of the input, so use `t1[i]` (i.e. the period will be found on the *next* loop iteration)

---

Here is a working version of your code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 256

int
main()
{

    char t1[STR_LEN],
     digits[STR_LEN],
    *dpt,
     per[2] = ".";
    int i, idig,
     digit,
     period;
    double x;

    fgets(t1, STR_LEN, stdin);

    idig = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(t1); i++) {
        digit = isdigit(t1[i]);
        period = (t1[i] == '.') ? 1 : 0;
        if (digit) {
            digits[idig++] = t1[i];
            digits[idig] = 0;
        }
        if (period == 1) {
            //strcpy(digits, digits);
            strcat(digits, per);
            idig += 1;
        }
    }
    x = strtod(digits, &dpt);
    int testOutput = strlen(digits);

    printf("%s %d %lf\n", digits, testOutput, x);

    return 0;
}
```

---

I've simplified the code a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 256

int
main()
{
    char t1[STR_LEN];
    char digits[STR_LEN];
    char *dpt;
    int isrc, idig;
    int len;
    int chr;
    double x;

    fgets(t1, STR_LEN, stdin);

    len = strlen(t1);

    idig = 0;
    for (isrc = 0;  isrc < len;  ++isrc) {
        chr = t1[isrc];

        if (isdigit(chr)) {
            digits[idig++] = chr;
            continue;
        }

        if (chr == '.') {
            digits[idig++] = chr;
            continue;
        }
    }

    digits[idig] = 0;

    x = strtod(digits, &dpt);
    int testOutput = strlen(digits);

    printf("%s %d %lf\n", digits, testOutput, x);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's a third version that uses `char *` pointers instead of index variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 256

int
main()
{
    char t1[STR_LEN];
    char digits[STR_LEN];
    char *dpt;
    char *src;
    char *dst;
    int isrc, idig;
    int len;
    int chr;
    double x;

    fgets(t1, sizeof(t1), stdin);

    src = t1;
    dst = digits;

    for (chr = *src++;  chr != 0;  chr = *src++) {
        if (isdigit(chr)) {
            *dst++ = chr;
            continue;
        }

        if (chr == '.') {
            *dst++ = chr;
            continue;
        }
    }

    *dst = 0;

    x = strtod(digits, &dpt);
    int testOutput = strlen(digits);

    printf("%s %d %lf\n", digits, testOutput, x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `if (isdigit(chr) || chr == '.')` ?

Comment: @emi I considered that. I chose to leave the `if`s separate to [better] illustrate the use of `continue` to minimize indenting and increase speed. Also, sometimes, the parsers for this want to do something special/different for `.` (e.g. direct parsing of the digit string _without_ use of `strtod` at the bottom).

Comment: In fact, you don't need any continue, here: it's already the end of the `for` block.

Comment: @emi The [second] `continue` is planning for the future. Suppose we [later] decided to reverse the order of the `if` statements. Or, at the bottom of the `for` loop, we [later] added an error message/warning about invalid syntax. Or, we chose to support (e.g.) `3.75e5` notation

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you very much for the quick and clear response, even the multiple solutions, it's amazing, I'll make sure to learn my lesson for the problems o come and continue exploring C. Also, the rest of you that commented and answered thank you, I really appreciate you investing your time and contributing. Have a great evening.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Pair {
   double first;
   double second;
   struct Pair * tail;
};

void printPairs( const struct Pair * node ) {
   if( node->tail ) {
      printPairs( node->tail );
   }
   printf( "[ %3.2f ; %3.2f ]\n", node->first, node->second );
}

int main() {
   const char *  input = "some words before {[ 5.1 ; 4 ], [15.3 ; -3.2] } some words after";
   struct Pair * head  = NULL, * p = NULL;
   char * err   = NULL;
   double first, second;
   const char * s = strchr( input, '{' );
   while( s ) {
      s = strchr( s, '[' );
      if( ! s ) {
         break;
      }
      while( *s == ' ' || *s == '[' ) {
         ++s;
      }
      first = strtod( s, &err );
      if( err && ( *err == ' ' || *err == ';' )) {
         s = err + 1;
         while( *s == ' ' || *s == ';' ) {
            ++s;
         }
         second = strtod( s, &err );
         if( err && ( *err == ' ' || *err == ']' )) {
            p = (struct Pair *)calloc( 1, sizeof( struct Pair ));
            p->first  = first;
            p->second = second;
            p->tail   = head;
            head = p;
         }
         else {
            fprintf( stderr, "Parse error, space or ']' expected\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
         }
      }
      else {
         fprintf( stderr, "Parse error, space or ';' expected\n" );
         exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
      }
   }
   printPairs( head );
}
```

Output:

```
[ 5.10 ; 4.00 ]
[ 15.30 ; -3.20 ]
```

Comment: This seems a little bit out of my level yet. When I am more capable in C I will certainly go back to your code and study it through and through. Thank you very much!